# script not producing result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

New to javascript. Would very much like to produce a simple calculator that uses three inputs and 4 fixed values to produce and report a 'peak power output' value. Code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    "use strict";
    /*jslint browser:true */
    function calculate() {
    var vj, hgt, wgt, result, peakresult;
    vj = document.getElementById('vjump');
    hgt = document.getElementById('height');
    wgt = document.getElementById('weight');
    result = document.getElementById('peakresult');
    peakresult = (78.6 * vj) + (60.3 * hgt) - (15.3 * wgt) - 1308;
    result.value = peakresult;
}
</script>
```

html:

```
<td>
    <input id="vj" type="text" oninput="calculate()" />
</td>
<td>
    <input id="hgt" type="text" oninput="calculate()" />
</td>
<td>
    <input id="wgt" type="text" oninput="calculate()" />
</td>
```

have this in a html page with table to display input and results, input works, but not results.

Comment: `vj`, `hgt`, and `wgt` don't contain what you think they do. Step 1: `console.log(vj,hgt,wgt)`

Comment: What types of elements are vjump, height, and weight?

Comment: not related but you will want to remove `enter code here"use strict";` also

Comment: document.getElementById return Dom Node, not the content of the node. then you cannot use it to calculate anything.

Comment: so how do I get the value from the input box named vjump into the var "vj"?

Comment: Please don't dump code to comments @user3666096 - edit your post and add any code that you have in the post.

Comment: Then you must use Number(GetElementById('vj').Value) to get the value of the input.

Comment: @mts7; the elements are input values on the html page.

Comment: @GuillaumePelletier, so replace 'document.get' portion with 'Number(GetElement')etc..?

Comment: @G.Mendes, thanks, I will remove that 'strict' line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you replace

```
vj = document.getElementById('vjump');
hgt = document.getElementById('height');
wgt = document.getElementById('weight');
```

by

```
vj = Number(document.getElementById('vjump').value);
hgt = Number(document.getElementById('height').value);
wgt = Number(document.getElementById('weight').value);
```

It should work.

BUT WITH NO check for correct input.

(EDITED)

This following code is working (Tested on Chrome)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<script>
    function calculate() {
        var vj, hgt, wgt, result, peakresult;
        vj = Number(document.getElementById('vj').value);
        hgt = Number(document.getElementById('hgt').value);
        wgt = Number(document.getElementById('wgt').value);
        result = document.getElementById('peakresult');
        peakresult = (78.6 * vj) + (60.3 * hgt) - (15.3 * wgt) - 1308;
        result.value = peakresult;
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <td>
        <input id="vj" type="text" oninput="calculate()" value="1"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="hgt" type="text" oninput="calculate()" value="1"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="wgt" type="text" oninput="calculate()" value="1"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="peakresult" type="text" value="0"/>
    </td>

</body>
```

Comment: Just tested on Chrome. Working :-).

Comment: Excellent, yes it works very well! Thank you very much!

Comment: does each of the input boxes need to retain the value "1"? or can they stay blank?

Comment: finally, how to round the result to 2 decimal places? do I add result =document.getElementById('peakresult'.value (Math.round(amt*100)/100).toFixed(2);

Comment: I modified peakresult = (Math.floor(78.6 * vj) + (60.3 * hgt) - (15.3 * wgt) - 1308).toFixed(2);  and that rounded to 2 decimals.

Answer (score 1):

You have jquery tagged, so here is a jQuery version.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
"use strict";
/*jslint browser:true */
function calculate() {
    var vj, hgt, wgt, result, peakresult;
    vj = $('#vj').val();
    hgt = $('#hgt').val();
    wgt = $('#wgt').val();
    result = $('#peakresult');
    peakresult = (78.6 * vj) + (60.3 * hgt) - (15.3 * wgt) - 1308;
    result.val(peakresult);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="text"]').on('blur', function() {
        calculate();
    });
});
</script>
```

This assumes you also have `<input type="text" id="peakresult" />` in your HTML.

I added a jQuery event handler that will call the calculate button when the user leaves the input field. That could be more useful than having a handler in the field tag.

Comment: and make my html input the same names?

Comment: I had the input id = the var name, (input id ="vj") it should be input name ="vjump", yes?

Comment: Yes, you can switch ids. Sorry about that. I edited my answer to fit your example.

Comment: No worries. My fault. As stated, new to this. Thank you.

Comment: When you find an answer that works for you, please be sure to accept it. :-)

Comment: Yes, I will post the final solution when it is discovered.

Comment: THis is what I have for input fields, is this also incorrect?
  <tr>
    <td><input id="vjump" type="text" oninput="calculate()" /></td>

Comment: If you use the HTML posted, my updated code should work for it. I'd suggest either changing oninput to onkeydown or onblur or removing oninput and using the jQuery event handler in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use unary plus, +, to turn your values into a number and then perform operations on them:

```
function add() {
  var a = +document.getElementById('firstOperand').value;
  var b = +document.getElementById('secondOperand').value;
  return a + b;
}
```

Also your html suggests you are invoking the calculate function every keystroke by using `oninput`. You can use `onblur` to call the calculate function after the user leaves the field.

Answer (score 0):

You might need parse text into integer

```
    parseInt(val);
```

Check this live sample 
http://jsfiddle.net/VdrWL/2/

Hope it helps.